# Where can I find a detailed explanation of how to set up netty?

Tags: java, maven, installation, netty, nio

I've been searching for a good nio framework for creating a server/client system, and netty seems to be perfect for my needs. But, I am having a lot of trouble setting up. Do I have to use maven? Because I never have before and I am having trouble setting that up, too... can't seem to find a decent guide for it. I'm pretty new with this stuff. I'm use to just writing java applications in eclipse either by itself or simply with external jars... but never through maven. Where can I find a detailed explanation of how to set up netty that even a newbie like me could comprehend?

Answer (score 0):

Netty doesn't have any external dependencies. All you need is one single jar that you can [download here](https://github.com/downloads/netty/netty/netty-3.5.5.Final-dist.tar.bz2). Once downloaded you can define it as an external dependency of your project in eclipse. Maven is an overkill for the simple purposes.